# Rcpp and C++ dependencies to gdal, sqlite3 and boost

Tags: sqlite, boost, dependencies, rcpp, gdal

I am trying to make an hybrid C++/python/R project more easily available for non-programmers.

I am considering the possibility to wrap the C++ code with Rcpp to make it available within an R package and hopefully hide some of the complexity to the end-user.

This question aims to understand to which extend it would be actually easier.

For example, when trying to source my `project.cpp`, I get  the following error:

```
fatal error: gdal_priv.h: No such file or directory #include <gdal_priv.h>
```

- Is it possible to write something cross-platform similar to `LinkingTo: BH, GDAL, sqlite3` ?
- How to know what C++ libraries have been made compatible with Rcpp (like BH for Boost)?
- The C++ sub-project works fine using cmake: can I somehow take advantage of these cmake files to help Rcpp finding the external dependencies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really three questions.

For 1) I do not know if/how `gdal` and or `sqlite3` export themselves as *header-only* libraries. I kinda doubt it; `gdal` is well-known, and also somewhat well-know as a source of "trouble" when building.  GeoSpatial foks may know and can possibly help you.

For 2), the question is ill-defined. What is "compatible with Rcpp" supposed to mean?  There are currently over 1800 packages on CRAN using Rcpp; maybe take those as an "existence proof" and search among them?

For 3), R and CRAN use `autoconf` / `configure` a *lot* more than `cmake`. You can of course use `cmake`, but you then need to declare that dependency in `SystemRequirements`.

In short, packaging *external* libraries is still difficult, chiefly because *you* now have to look after their installation on up to three different operating systems.  This has nothing to do with Rcpp, and Rcpp cannot really help. :-/

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer. I imagined that the R packaging system and Rcpp would make it easier to handle external dependencies, but it seems I was wrong :)

Comment: The infamous "No Free Lunch" theorem comes at us again!  I wish it was easier, I am fighting that very issue myself in a few projects.  Header-only really is the best, sadly not all projects can be expressed that way.  Docker can be a way out though.

Comment: "You can not have both the butter and the butter money" is the equivalent French idiom ;) Docker was next in my list of way out. Next I was thinking about snap to make it easy at least on Ubuntu.
Why is header-only easier to manage ? Because it makes possible to just copy the files in the R package ?

Comment: You know, snap is interesting but ... more difficult. I was at a Ubuntu-organized hackathon for it last year and we couldn't really get R done for package building reasons.  Try Docker. _Et enfin: on dit ca comment en Francais?_

Comment: Bye bye snap then ! Your feedback saves me some time, thank you!
"On ne peut pas avoir le beurre et l'argent du beurre" ;)

Comment: Mind you snap may work to just wrap a package and its libraries. We couldn;t really ship R as an extensible system as the compilable extensions (you know, Rcpp) run afoul the path and env settings of snap.  Too bad really.  But I use some apps as snap and it is good system, and more direct than Docker.

Comment: Ok! I may give it a try after Docker, it seems an interesting system!